# Quickblox Android push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

I am trying to implement push notification in my android application through quickblox API. 
All the  steps (registration,  create push token  , create subscription )are successfully executed  but finally  its throwing the following error message.

> "No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for GCM
>   (Android Push) (through SDK or REST API)"

I am not getting  getting any clue on this error

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem in iPhone. You are trying to send push notification to the user who has not subscribe yet or no one has subscribed for push notification.

**What can you do** : - run your application in actual device and run application in simulator with different login. And try to send push notification.

Answer (score 1):

To which user you send Push Notification?

I thing you are trying to send push to user which is not subscribed  for GCM (Android Push), and you got an error: "No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for GCM (Android Push)"

Comment: Please let me know how to subscribe user  for GCM

Comment: You already wrote it: (3 steps: create session with user, create push token , create subscription). Thats all

Comment: Hey Igor i have a question regarding quickblox android sdk please visit this link: stackoverflow.com/questions/33979739/quick-blox-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You must register your device through the method `GCMRegistrar.register()` , please try to run on real phone rather than emulator. I also got the same error. But it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer, I solved this issue,
After subscription of push just logout from Quickblox to receive push notification.

Comment: hello PKR, can you elaborate on your answer, i am facing similar issue.  Push works only when the opponent application is closed